# How to change application settings (Settings) while app is open?

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I've written a class that should allow me to easily read and write values in app settings:

```
public static class SettingsManager
    {
        public static string ComplexValidationsString
        {
            get { return (string)Properties.Settings.Default["ComplexValidations"]; }
            set
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default["ComplexValidations"] = value;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

the problem is the value isn't really saved, I mean it is not changed when I exit the application and run it again. What can I do to ensure that the saved value persists between closing and opening again?

Comment: That should be saving, I don't see any problems with it in my eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["ComplexValidations"].IsReadOnly
```

It is probably true, this is what Roland means with "Application Scope". Save will fail silently.  Take a look at Project|Properties|Settings, 3rd column.

Answer (score 11):

settings scope  must be user not application

Comment: Add before your setting in Settings.designer.cs
 [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
or simply change the scope in settings1.settings

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not saving the changes? The [ProgramName].exe.config file in the bin folder won't be updated. The acutal file used is usually put in `C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\Local Settings\Application Data\[company name]\[application].exe[hash string]\[version]\user.config`. I know when I tried this kind of thing it took me a while to realise this was the file that was getting updated.

Comment: whichever file it is updating, as a result I would like to see the value of ComplexValidationsString to be set to the value set in the previous time the app was opened.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a User Setting and it is persisted if you run this Console app twice:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Settings1.Default.Setting);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Settings1.Default.Setting = "A value different from app.config's";
        Settings1.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Just try it out. It won't take a minute.